# Как получить VID:PID для USB Hub в Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, usb

Имею symbolic link на USB Root Hub вида "\\.\USB#ROOT_HUB#4&e097488&0#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8}" и хочу получить VID:PID для хаба.
Работаю в user mode, IOCTLы слать могу. Но среди описанных в MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff537421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) не нахожу подходящего. Как быть?

Answer (score 4):

VID и PID для USB Hub можно определить разбором его [Hardware ID](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/standard-usb-identifiers). Hardware ID можно получить с помощью функции [SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551967(v=vs.85).aspx) (Setup API). Функция возвращает несколько значений, нужно взять первое с вхождением подстрок VID/PID. Для корневого концентратора формат строки выглядит так:

> USB\ROOT_HUB30&VID8086&PID8C31&REV0005

Пример кода на c++ для вывода symbolic link, названия, VID и PID для всех USB Hub-ов; основан на [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36728329/8674428).

```
#pragma comment(lib,"Setupapi.lib")

#include <Windows.h>
#include <Setupapi.h>
#include <winusb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Devpkey.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <strsafe.h>


void ErrorMes(LPTSTR lpszFunction) 
{ 
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    // Display the error message 

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    wprintf(L"%s failed with error %d: %s", 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);     

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);

}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");

    GUID guid;


    HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromString(L"{F18A0E88-C30C-11D0-8815-00A0C906BED8}", (LPCLSID)&guid);//USB Hub

    HDEVINFO deviceInfoHandle = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&guid, 0, 0, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);

    if (deviceInfoHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        int deviceIndex = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInterface = { 0 };
            deviceInterface.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);

            //перечисление всех интерфейсов USB Hub
            if (SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(deviceInfoHandle, 0, &guid, deviceIndex, &deviceInterface))
            {
                DWORD cbRequired = 0;

                SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(deviceInfoHandle, &deviceInterface, 0, 0, &cbRequired, 0);
                if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == GetLastError())
                {
                    PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA deviceInterfaceDetail = 
                        (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)(new char[cbRequired]);
                    memset(deviceInterfaceDetail, 0, cbRequired);
                    deviceInterfaceDetail->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

                    if (!SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(deviceInfoHandle, &deviceInterface, deviceInterfaceDetail, 
                        cbRequired, &cbRequired, 0))
                    {
                        deviceIndex++;
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Initialize the structure before using it.
                    memset(deviceInterfaceDetail, 0, cbRequired);
                    deviceInterfaceDetail->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

                    // Call the API a second time to retrieve the actual
                    // device path string.
                    BOOL status = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
                        deviceInfoHandle,  // Handle to device information set
                        &deviceInterface,     // Pointer to current node in devinfo set
                        deviceInterfaceDetail,   // Pointer to buffer to receive device path
                        cbRequired,   // Length of user-allocated buffer
                        &cbRequired,  // Pointer to arg to receive required buffer length
                        NULL);        // Not interested in additional data

                    wprintf(deviceInterfaceDetail->DevicePath);//вывод symbolic link
                    wprintf(L"\n");

                    //получение информации о устройстве
                    DEVPROPTYPE dpt=0;
                    wchar_t buffer[1000]=L"";
                    DWORD RequiredSize = 0;
                    SP_DEVINFO_DATA devinfo = { 0 };
                        devinfo.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);

                    BOOL success = SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(deviceInfoHandle, deviceIndex, &devinfo);
                    if(success==FALSE){ErrorMes(L"SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo");}

                    BOOL res;

                    //name
                    res=SetupDiGetDeviceProperty(deviceInfoHandle,&devinfo,
                        &DEVPKEY_Device_DeviceDesc,&dpt,(PBYTE)buffer,1000,NULL,0);

                    printf("Name: ");
                    if(res==FALSE)ErrorMes(L"SetupDiGetDeviceProperty");
                    else wprintf(buffer);
                    printf("\n");

                    //hardware id
                    DWORD regType = REG_MULTI_SZ;
                    unsigned char* ptr = new unsigned char[2048];
                    if (SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(deviceInfoHandle, &devinfo, SPDRP_HARDWAREID, &regType, 
                        ptr, 2048, &RequiredSize))
                    {
                        wchar_t* input=reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(ptr);
                        wchar_t sep[]=L"&\\";
                        wchar_t vid[5]=L"";
                        wchar_t pid[5]=L"";
                        bool found=false;

                        /*проходим по всем элементам REG_MULTI_SZ*/
                        while(true){

                            wchar_t* tok=NULL;
                            wchar_t* pos=NULL;

                            //разбор hardware id
                            tok=wcstok(input,sep);
                            while( tok != NULL )  
                            {                       
                                pos=wcsstr(tok,L"VID");

                                if(pos!=NULL){                          
                                    pos+=3;
                                    if(pos[0]==L'_')pos++;
                                    StringCchCopy(vid,5,pos);   
                                    found=true;
                                }

                                pos=wcsstr(tok,L"PID");

                                if(pos!=NULL){                          
                                    pos+=3;
                                    if(pos[0]==L'_')pos++;
                                    StringCchCopy(pid,5,pos);
                                    found=true;
                                }

                                tok = wcstok( NULL, sep ); 
                            }//конец разбора hardware id

                            if(found!=false)break;

                            input+=wcslen(input)+1;//переход к следующему элементу REG_MULTI_SZ

                            if(wcscmp(input,L"")==0)break;
                        }//конец прохода

                        if(found!=false)
                        {
                            wprintf( L"VID: %s\n", vid );
                            wprintf( L"PID: %s\n", pid );                           
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            wprintf( L"Not found\n");
                        }

                    }
                    else ErrorMes(L"SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty");

                    delete[] ptr;
                    delete[] deviceInterfaceDetail;

                    printf("\n");                   

                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

            ++deviceIndex;
        }

        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(deviceInfoHandle);
    }


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```